# Land search software/API?

Tags: python, api, gps, geo-location, land-surveying

I'm looking for a software or Python API to search for land in the US that fits certain criteria.

Like, "here is every square mile in the US, here is every single measure thing about them (including interpolated estimates), write a prioritization function/constraints, and we'll spit out the exact coordinates for where to build your house/cabin/whatever."

I'm talking crazy granular, like it can calculate (or very easily have inputted) things like "interpolated average land price" or "distance to nearest Wal-Mart" or "urban center within biking distance boolean".

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The [Wikidata Query Service](https://query.wikidata.org/) can do a lot already, and the only limits are your imagination, your time, and your programming skills.

There are lots of example queries on that page. Click on "Examples" A big modal dialog with a long list of example queries will open.

You'll have to scroll down the list quite a bit, to see some examples with geographical context. E.g. ["Places within 1 sqare km within the Empire State Building"](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fplace%20%3FplaceLabel%20%3Flocation%20%3FinstanceLabel%0AWHERE%0A%7B%0A%20%20wd%3AQ9188%20wdt%3AP625%20%3Floc%20.%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Aaround%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fplace%20wdt%3AP625%20%3Flocation%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Acenter%20%3Floc%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Aradius%20%221%22%20.%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%20%20%20%3Fplace%20wdt%3AP31%20%3Finstance%20%20%7D%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22%20%7D%0A%20%20BIND(geof%3Adistance(%3Floc%2C%20%3Flocation)%20as%20%3Fdist)%0A%7D%20ORDER%20BY%20%3Fdist), NYC

Python package: [qwikidata](https://qwikidata.readthedocs.io/en/stable/readme.html) and probably others.

If you want to bring in your own dataset (e.g. about current  prices for real estate), then you can do that too. But Wikidata probably does not have such market data.